# An url gets redirected from browser, but not with fetch

Tags: node.js, redirect, fetch, response

I want to detect if an url redirects to another one, and if so, get the url of redirected website. Lets get https://eu.gymshark.com as an example.

When I go to that link on my browser, it redirects to https://eu.shop.gymshark.com, but when I run the code below, I still get https://eu.gymshark.com as output. What should I do?

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch")

async function getRedirects(url){
    const header = new fetch.Headers( {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'})
    let response = await fetch(url, {"headers": header, redirect: 'follow', follow: 10})
    
    return response.url

}
getRedirects("https://eu.gymshark.com").then((data) => console.log(data));
```

PS: Code works fine in the case of https://dior.com.my/ which redirects to https://shop.dior.com.my/

Answer (score 0):

The site isn't redirecting.  It is using JavaScript to change the URL.

To be able to detect this type of URL change the same way that browsers do, you would have to download the entire page and all its assets, then run the JavaScript for some time and watch for changes to `window.location`.

This isn't a trivial thing to do, but it is possible. Search engine bots like Googlebot now work this way. You can search for "headless crawler" or "headless javascript render" to find projects and products that would help you get started with it.